# Do the vertex and fragment run over all points or just the ones left after clipping?

Tags: opengl, graphics, metal

Im trying to wrap my head around the GPU pipeline and the performance implications...

I create a coordinate system and put a million vertices on it, all of them are now in memory usable by the GPU. I assume this is the performance hit on this step: moving all the floating values into the GPU memory, implying the points where already created.

Then I transform my million points coordinates into clipping coordinates. Here I’m applying a transformation to each point.

As a result of this transformation some points are now outside of the clip coordinates, let’s say only a thousands points are in. Does the vertex shader run on the thousand or all million points? What about the fragment shader? And the building of triangles? Transformation into the final device coordinates only takes the thousand points?

My guess is that the vertex runs on all but the fragment only on the interpolation of the visible vertices.

Is the only optimization possible then to just include as little vertices as possible in the first place? If I’m looking at a full 3D world with buildings, trees, roads... and then zoom at just one rock I’m running all the shaders on all the objects anywhay... so the only solution would be to not put those trees and buildings in the first place? Or can I have this world on GPU memory but just compute the rock? Could I apply the transformation of coordinates to just the rock somehow? Where in the pipeline a technique like GPU culling, level of detail or dynamic tessellation takes place?

Comment: Your question seems decidedly... confused as to the nature of the rendering pipeline. You talk about having "coordinate system"s and "transform my million points coordinates into clipping coordinates" as if these things are somehow not part of the rendering pipeline. As if these things are not *what vertex shaders do*.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex shaders are executed for each vertex submitted with `glDrawArrays` and `glDrawElements` function families, perhaps even multiple times per vertex. The transformed vertices are then assembled into primitives and clipped—if it's outside the viewport then their processing is done. To reduce the overhead of processing vertices of objects outside the viewport multiple techniques are employed. The simplest one is "frustum culling"—submit the object for rendering only if its bounding box intersects the camera frustum.

Fragment shaders are executed for each fragment ("pixel") in the framebuffer that passes the depth test. One way to reduce their count is to render front to back—so that only the front-visible fragments are ever calculated.